# How to retrieve the thumbnail from a .blend file?

Tags: python, blend-files

I would like to retrieve `.blend` file thumbnails without using Blender at all, just plain old python3.

Also if it would be possible to explain how the `.blend` file works and how the process of retrieving the thumbnail works?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23271/1853

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is possible and infact has been done already,
the script to do this comes bundled with Blender: see [blender-thumbnailer.py](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/bin/blender-thumbnailer.py).

This Python script runs without Blender, eg extracting a PNG image from `my.blend`:

```
blender-thumbnailer.py /input/my.blend /output/thumb.png
```

---

### Details

To extract the thumbnail from a `.blend` file you have to use a basic `.blend` file parser, however - this is written in such a way that its quite simple to extract the data without having to understand the entire blend file format, instead - you only need to read one of the serialized `BHead` blocks. (See link above).

Using `blender-thumbnailer.py` as a reference: writing this in another programming language, or saving as a different image format should not be a very big task.