# Restore thumbnails in Windows File Explorer?

Tags: windows

I remember Blender use to produce thumbnails in file explorer. I'm not sure what happened, but I've recently reformatted windows and installed 2.76b, and it still doesn't show them. I assume this isn't something on my end, and I found this thread which makes it seem as if there is something wrong with the installer:

https://developer.blender.org/T45389

My question is: is there anyway to manually fix it?

Comment: The *.blend files open no problem, they just don't show a thumbnail of the scene. Instead it's the blender logo.

Comment: maybe related ? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23269/batch-generate-preview-thumbnail-image-for-old-files/23271#23271

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer courtesy of fmb501 at blenderartists [(thread here)](http://www.blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?372289-Blend-files-not-using-preview-thumbnails-in-windows-explorer) :

> This appears to be a bug in the Blender installer, but the fix is
>   fairly simple.
>
> Open the Windows icon in the bottom left corner of your computer
>   display and search for "command prompt"
>
> Right click on the result and select "run as administrator."
>
> There will be a small window with a black background and a blinking
>   cursor.
>
> Type "chdir c:\program files\blender foundation\blender" and press
>   Enter (chdir is the command for changing directories with the command
>   prompt)
>
> You should now be at that directory.
>
> Type "blender -R" and press enter. You should receive a message
>   indicating that the registration has been successful.
>
> Close any Windows Explorer windows and then open Windows Explorer
>   again.
>
> Navigate to a directory that has your blend files and you should now
>   see thumbnails for all of your blend files. If there some blend files
>   that don't have thumbnails, it's probably an old file before the
>   thumbnails were added. Just open and save it again and you should see
>   the thumbnail.
>
> I'm not sure why Blender Foundation hasn't fixed this instalation
>   problem by now. I'm wondering if you have to install blender as an
>   administrator to get it to regiser the thumbnail dll.
>
> Anyway, until it gets fixed, you will likely have to register as
>   described above with every new installation.

Answer (score 2):

If all else failed. Try this.

Download an older version of blender installer. I used version 2.66a from their previous versions archive. Since it's only 300MB I keep the 2.66a version on my harddisk. After installation of the older version your thumbnails should start working again.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there's an error in 2.79b version (on Win 10 1809) on registering shell extension. I ran "blender -R" command and it was successful, but no thumbnails appeared on `.blend` files. I searched the registry and found that the corresponding key written in `.blend —> ShellEx —> {e357fccd-a995-4576-b01f-234630154e96}` subkey (on my system it is `{D45F043D-F17F-4e8a-8435-70971D9FA46D}`) is only present in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID`. So I copied that key to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID` also. And the thumbnails appeared (no need to restart Windows Explorer or rebuild the icon cache, just F5).

Comment: This worked for me where the first answer didn't do anything!

Answer (score 2):

KoolMode's answer was my savior until I installed Windows 10 from Windows 7.
Now (after navigating the explanation and registry) danissimo's answer is my savior.

I manually retyped the data in the Registry Editor but I exported it for your convenience.
Copy Paste this text into notepad or whatever and save it as *[filename]***.reg**, then open/run it.
Or run ***regedit.exe*** then go to File > Import > Find your file

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{D45F043D-F17F-4e8a-8435-70971D9FA46D}]
@="Blender Thumbnail Handler"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{D45F043D-F17F-4e8a-8435-70971D9FA46D}\InProcServer32]
@="C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\BlendThumb.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"
```

Answer (score 1):

"Show Thumbnails" is an option in Blender's User Preferences.

Just go to the User Preferences, click the top "File" tab, and then from there just click "Show Thumbnails" on.

Comment: I've had that checked, it either doesn't work or is for Blender's UI only.

Comment: In Blender 3.0 I had to set the File preview type. Preferences ->Save&Load->File preview Type->screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Running blender.exe -r with 2.93 or 3.0.0 alpha and Window 10 doesn't seem to work anymore, Danissimo's registry hack didn't work either.

Only thing I found works, is copying an older `BlendThumb.dll` from Blender 2.81 and place it in 2.93 folder and run blender.exe -r again.
See https://developer.blender.org/T84599