# Get Blender files to save with a thumbnail preview?

Tags: customization, blend-files

Is there a way to have Blender save a preview of the scene for use as the file-system thumbnail preview? It would make it much easier to review old files.

To clarify, I would like to see the preview image in Finder, like normal image files.

**EDIT**

Mac OS X Mavericks, Blender 2.77

I have **Preferences > File > Show Thumbnails & Save Preview Images** check marked.

**EDIT**

I understand that there is a python script that extracts a thumbnail, but it does not meet my needs:

- Doesn't apply the thumbnail as the icon on Mac OS for me.
- Isn't generated on save / doesn't update.
- The batch script requires the .blend files to be in the same directory; my files are all over.

Unless I'm using the script wrong, it's not really what I want.

Comment: Blender does this already. What OS/file explorer are you using?

Comment: @someonewithpc - added to question; Mac with Bender 2.77

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic because it's not about Blender. This is a file browser specific thing. For instance, Thunar doesn't do this, by default, but Firefox's does.

Comment: @someonewithpc - I don't understand, wouldn't Blender have to generate the thumbnail image for the file-system to use?

Comment: Yes, that's what `blender-thumbnailer.py` does.

Comment: @someonewithpc - I've used that script, and it does generate an image, but I would have to apply it to the file as a thumbnail manually, and it would not automatically update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42628/discussion-between-karric-and-someonewithpc).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch generate preview/thumbnail image for old files?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23269/batch-generate-preview-thumbnail-image-for-old-files)

Comment: hmm, i have a quickviewer built for this particular reason

Comment: ha! i know i'm late for the party but in a couple' o weeks ill get my viewer up here

Comment: I get it working for my windows 10 by `blender -R` in command prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Kinda Late but here's what I found...

---

I ran into this post about 4 months ago with the same problem you had, after some googling and some realization that this was not currently possible I decided to change my direction of googling.

With the little knowledge of Xcode and Obj-C I had I decided to attempt to slap this together...

---

#### Please note:

It's not as err "optimized" as a well seasoned coder may make it, but it's enough to do the job.
So far I have had pretty good luck with it and I hope you fellows do to

Also I've found that the thumbnails that blender makes are low-quality, so its not as pretty as I hoped it would be.
And lastly i've noticed that it does not allways succeed in creating icons for the desktop (odd).

---

### Installation

It's quite easy, download the QuickLookViewer [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3phj2-3Wce6RDJSLWhsaDlsTWM/view?usp=sharing) and move it to either `~/Library/Quicklook` or `/Library/Quicklook` if the folder `Quicklook` does not exist there feel free to create it. Please notice that the one location is local in your account and the other is global on the whole computer.

Next you need to update the Quicklook engine...

Either log out and log back in (the hard solution I might add).

Or simply type the following in Terminal and hit the return key

```
qlmanage -r
```

This will force the ql engine to reset...

last of all cheers and good luck!
I guess this is my contribution to the Blender project for now! (until they implement it later cause they should)

Comment: also if its buggy and you got problems please tell me here, i come on SE about every fortnight ;)