# Automate renderings of simple scene with phyton

Tags: rendering, scripting

I have this simple lighting scene that i need to apply to 50 cars. Do you know the script to automate the following steps?:

1. Import car to the scene
2. Apply my white car paint material
3. Render it and save
4. Import the next car and repeat

Any help is welcome.

[image]

Comment: This is an unpaid job request. What did you try and what failed?

Comment: Hello and welcome. This question seems to have been asked before in multiple forms over time, and already has various answers but you never acknowledged any of them. We are not sure if you aware of the existing posts but none of the described techniques address your particular requisites, or you simply didn't do any research at all. Could you [edit] you post and clarify how your question differs from the suggested duplicates? Otherwise could you rephrase it to focus on a particular step you are stuck with?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/241373/rendering-objects-one-by-one/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/218730/automatically-generate-100-animations-each-with-a-different-texture-input https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23269/batch-generate-preview-thumbnail-image-for-old-files/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/313/is-there-a-way-to-batch-render-multiple-scenes